# how to get a value from list item by clicking

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i am working with uwp i need to get the value the selecteditem from list and get the details of the employee

the details of the employee is store in

```
 List<EmployeeItem> Employeelist = DataAccess.getallemployee(empdetails);
```

i need to get the detail of a selected employee from the list

```css
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeListView" Width="auto" Grid.Row="4" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="EmployeeListView_ItemClick">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:EmployeeItem">
      <TextBlock x:Name="firstname" Grid.Column="0" 
                Text="{Binding FirstName}" 
                       FontSize="17" />
```

my click fucntion is

```
private void EmployeeListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(seleted));
}
```

Comment: `ItemClickEventArgs` has a `ClickedItem` property that you can use.

Comment: Does my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Click event`:

```
    private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var firstSelectedItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you are using single selection mode in your ListView. It is suggested to handle the `SelectionChanged Event` to get the selected item and do what you want in the next.

You could check more information here: [ListView Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview?view=winrt-22621#remarks).

**Xaml:**

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeListView" Width="auto" Grid.Row="4"  SelectionChanged="EmployeeListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:EmployeeItem">
                <TextBlock x:Name="firstname" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="17" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
 private void EmployeeListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeItem item = EmployeeListView.SelectedItem as EmployeeItem;
        //do what you want
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(seleted));
    }
```